# Referencing layout.xml from another package

Tags: android, cordova

I'm writing a Phonegap plugin that allows you to capture a screenshot of what is currently on the screen in an Android application, however I'm running into a few problems..

In order to have the plugin working, it must be in a separate package and .java file within the same application folder.

However, as I need to find the Android view by id I need to reference the layout.xml file and the data that is generated in R.java.

I'm using the following code to find the view:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutRoot);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
```

And R is flagging as an error, with the message: R cannot be resolved to a variable.

I know from trial and error that this error is because the view ID cannot be found as it exists outside the package.

Is there anyway I can reference this layout ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import the R class by adding `import xxx.yyy.zzz.R;` to the top of your file (where xxx.yyy.zzz is the package of the R class).